# Vba Copy a range and paste as a HIGH quality picture

Tags: excel, vba

Need a way to paste higher quality image

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for your time, I have a simple dashboard which copies a range of cells containing a table and a chart from another sheet and pastes it as a picture in the dashboard tab, it all works great except that the chart in the picture is VERY low quality and fine details are missing, is there a way to paste this at a higher resolution?

```
    Range("A1:O53").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dash").Select
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You will get the same detail and resolution that you have on the origin (you can improve just customizing the new area)... what are you meaning regarding higher resolution?

Comment: Thanks David for your comment, I've added two screenshots above, the top one is how it looks, the bottom is when the code copies it and pastes it in the dash sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to `Copy Picture`. Have a look here:
[Excel Vba Copy Picture to new sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46852565/78522)
or try the recorder.
On my Excel 2019 it does even record a `Copy` instruction, but works anyway.
I have been using Copy Picture quite often when preparing PowerPoint, the quality is much better.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I'm using Excel 2007, and when I select a range and right click, I don't get a "Copy Picture", note that I don't want to copy the entire sheet, I just need to copy a range of cells which includes a table and a chart, then paste that, as a picture, on the dashboard sheet.

Comment: Copy picture exists at least since 2003 ! Click the chart and click the arrow below copy in menu. Or shift-right-click object perhaps

Comment: I was missing what you were saying, I read up on the copy picture method and modified my code to this...

Comment: ```    Worksheets("Yearly").Range("A1:O53").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    Sheets("Dash").Select
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste.Select
```

It now pastes the picture in good resolution, thank you again so much for your help

Comment: Another problem now, when I use the code in the actual vba procedure, it pastes an empty picture if I use this line...

Comment: Worksheets("Yearly").Range("A1:O53").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap

But it will show correctly when I use the below line... (but bad quality)

Worksheets("Yearly").Range("A1:O53").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

Comment: I added this line before copying and it seems to be okay now...

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True